# Nginx Unicorn AngularJS html5 URLs configuration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, nginx, angular-ui-router, unicorn

I want to add pretty URLS in Angular UI-router. I have Nginx + Unicorn over a Rails app with Angular JS as the front-end.

I want to have pretty URLS like mysite/a/b/c, no '#' and no hashbang. When I change the location of nginx to:

```
server {
    server_name yoursite.com;
    root /path/to/app;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ @unicorn;
    }
}
```

Unicorn will throw this error:

> directory index of "/path/to/app" is forbidden

Any idea on how to setup nginx to redirect? Giving chmod to my app path isn't a good solution I believe..

**Edit:** The issue is that with try_files $uri/index @unicorn, it works e.g. url.com/a/b. But when I refresh, it automatically redirects me to root url.com. UI-router suggests try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html, but when I do this I get an access denied by nginx. The folder /path/to/app belongs to user 'deploy', so it's not a chmod issue..

Comment: Your application must have rights to access files at `/path/to/app` as set in the `root` directive.  At least in my case, I run my Rails/Unicorn application from the same user that is the owner of those files.

Comment: Is it safe to change the privileges of unicorn root?

Comment: Sorry Alex I don't think I understand - can you explain a little more?  I don't think you need to change any privileges, just run unicorn under the appropriate user and from the application folder.  There are probably other ways to do it but that is my approach.

Comment: I run it using Chef and AWS opsworks. The source/root folder is on /srv/app/.../public. Then chef takes those files and deploys with the user 'deploy' to /srv/app/.../shared. 

Now, if the rule is try_files $uri/index $uri/index.htm @unicorn; my app works fine, so this is the weird part (without the html5 /a/b/ links of course, but with /#/a/b). I don't have any index.html on my root folder and I don't understand why it works!!

Is your solution/suggestion to chown the files under /srv/app/...public by the user 'deploy'?

Comment: I use `mina` to manage my deploys but I think it is similar to `Chef`.  When I deploy, `mina` pulls my files from git and builds them in `/home/myapp/app/current/public` and makes user `myapp` owner.  This is my public Rails directory - it has assets plus some static error page files like 404.html - and is where my NGINX root directive points.  To start/restart the application, I run `/etc/init.d/unicorn.myapp` which, among other things, performs su - myapp to run Unicorn under myapp.  The Rails router handles routing of requests from this public directory to app/controllers etc.

Comment: Are the #'s you refer to in your links release numbers?  I have the same thing but mina is generating a symbolic link from ~/app/current to ~/app/releases/<biggest number> and also handles saving the last five versions here.  If Chef is doing something similar for you, you should be able to work within ../current and generally ignore this releases folder (unless you need to roll back or something).

Comment: Thank you Steve! I'll check and come back at you in the afternoon. The #'s are generated by angularjs ui-router, it produces links such as url.com/#/route1.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81031/discussion-between-alex-arvanitidis-and-steve-klein).

Comment: Sorry just saw this Alex.  I am not very familiar with Angular ui-router.  Do the routes literally have a segment with just a '#' and you are looking to remove this segment?  If so, you can definitely accomplish this with rewrite rules but I am guessing there may be a way to do within the application routing engine for Angular.

Comment: I edited the question to explain the issue a little bit more, I'll add a bounty because I really need the answer to this.

Comment: OK I see your edit.  GL with the bounty.  btw unless you have a rewrite somewhere, your app is redirecting you to root, not the web server.  I would also read up on try_files - it is pretty straightforward once you understand it.

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved it! It was my mistake, because running my app with angular I forgot in the rails routes.rb file this line:

```
get '*path' => '/'
```

Changed it to

```
get '*path' => 'layouts#index'
```

where layouts#index is my layout for Angular, and now after refreshing the url.com/a/b the url stays url.com/a/b and renders the appropriate route.

At nginx my config remained:

```
location /{
    try_files $uri @unicorn;
}
```